# How to submit after using ng-repeat, ng-form and ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms

I am using some data to get a list of Books as below:-

1 1001 - 500 - Lords of the Ring Reference(InputBox) Remarks(InputBox) SubmitBox

2 1002 - 570 - Harry Potter      Reference(InputBox) Remarks(InputBox) SubmitBox

3 1003 - 720 - Davinci Code      Reference(InputBox) Remarks(InputBox) SubmitBox

I am able to get above with codes below. But however, I do not know how to save the datas to another database and would be grateful if someone could guide me.

This is my html code:-

```
    <form name="Bookentry" ng-submit="save()">

        <div  ng-repeat="lists in list.Books | orderBy: ['numB','numB1' ]">

            <ng-form name="item">

                {{$index+1}}

                <input type="checkbox" ng-click="delete(lists._id)">{{lists.numB}} - {{lists.numB1}} - {{lists.bookname}}
                <input type="text" name="Reference" ng-model="lists.Reference" ng-maxlength="8" ng-minlength="1"></input>
                <input type="text" name="Remarks" ng-model="lists.Remarks" ng-maxlength="8" ng-minlength="1"></input>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </ng-form>
        </div>          
    </form>
```

My core.js codes is:-

```
$scope.save = function(){
    $http.post('/api/save',$scope.Bookentry)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.list = {};
            $scope.list.Books = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

My app.js is:

```
app.post('/api/save', function(req,res){

  dbBooks.create({
    numB: req.body.numB,
    numB1: req.body.numB1,
    name: req.body.bookname,
    Reference: req.body.Reference,
    remarks: req.body.remarks,
    done: false
  }, function(err,result){
    if (err)
        res.send(err);
    dbBooks.find(function(err,result){
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(result)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Send a JSON array to your server and iterate over the array?

Comment: I am a beginner and will need some more explanation please. thanks

Comment: What kind of REST api do you use?

Comment: i do not know what king of REST api I used. I do trial and error and tried the above codes but it is not working

Comment: If I look at your code, I see that you are doing a POST request to ````/api/save````. My question is, what are you using to handle these requests to this URL? This could be a webserver with PHP or JAVA(jax-rs).
It should be an URL like this: ````http://example.com/api/save````

Comment: I use nodejs, angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the lists model as parameter to the save function.
html code:

```
<form name="Bookentry" ng-submit="save(lists)">
```

core js:

```
$scope.save = function(bookEntry){
    $http.post('/api/save',bookEntry)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.list = {};
            $scope.list.Books = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
};
```

Comment: I tried it but how do i get the data in my app.js? thks